# Attach and View PDF Document on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a very basic app but I couldn't reach my point exactly. I just want to hit an 'Attach' button and choose a pdf document. Then I will read the pdf document on the iPhone.

I have tried `WebViewer` but it didn't work. So maybe there is another solution?

The code below works for showing pdf document if you attach while programming. I want that user will attach document.

```
let pdf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("myPDF", withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)  {
        let req = NSURLRequest(URL: pdf)
        let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(20,20,self.view.frame.size.width-40,self.view.frame.size.height-40))
        webView.loadRequest(req)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for what you have tried so far?

Comment: @matt Attach from iTunes maybe. What are the possibilities on iPhone?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do. PDF documents do not just magically fall from the sky into your app's sandbox. If your app doesn't already _have_ the PDF somewhere, you cannot magically obtain it. In your example, the PDF was already in your app bundle. That works.

Comment: @matt Let's say I downloaded the pdf document from e-mail. Then how can I see this document on this App?

Comment: And here is an app project that demonstrates it: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch23p802fileHandoff/ch36p1060fileHandoff

Comment: If i got you right you need to use https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller to show the dialog where user can chose open in safari / save to iBooks and then read it